# Disable button upon removing textview content

Tags: java, android

```
    public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    TextView tv;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=findViewById(R.id.button_chatbox_send);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        tv= findViewById(R.id.edittext_chatbox);
        tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (charSequence.toString().equals("")) {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
//Call other method with string from text view as parameter
            }
            }
        });
```

}

I added a TextChangedListener to my TextView to disabled the Button, while the text view contains no string. During runtime, after I entered a string into the TextView, the Button is still enabled, even if I deleted all the text. How do I solve this problem, the method which I use during on click can not work with an empty string?

***Edit***

Problem is solved ty.

Answer (score 1):

Update your button in onTextChanged or after textChanged

```
tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            button.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()));  // Update button here OR 

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            button.setEnabled(count>0); // Update button here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

move it to afterTextChanged

```
 @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        button.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editable.toString()));
    }
```

Comment: If I use this code, I receive an error : "Cannot resolve method 'getText()'

Comment: I removed the getText() method, the code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the button inside the `onTextChanged` method of the `TextWatcher` -

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    button.setEnabled(charSequence.toString().length() > 0);
}
```